# Show data with related radio button jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have different data for each radio button i want related div should be show under radio button.

currently every data is displaying below 1st radio button

Here is my code .

```
    <div class="portlet-body">
@foreach($students as $student)
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="{{$student->id}}" name="student_lists[]" onclick="getdata( {{ $student->id }} )"/>
        {{$lists->name}}
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="students-data"></div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function getdata(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/students/'+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#students-data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller method to get HTML**

```
public function loadData($id)
{
  $students = DB::table('students')->select('name' , 'id')->where('user_id' , $id)->get();
  $data = '';
    $data .= '<div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-1">
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <label class="">';
                          foreach ($students as $student) {
                              $data .= "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' name='custom' value='{$student->name}'/> {$student->name}
                                <span></span>";
                              }
                 $data .='</label>
                      </div>
                  </div>';
              return $data;
  }
```

on every selection of radio button data shows below 1st radio button but i want div should show under related radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not allowed to comment, so to reflect your latest "request".

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="{{$student->id}}" name="student_lists[]" onclick="getdata( {{ $student->id }} )"/>
        {{$lists->name}}
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="students-data" id="students-data-{{$student->id}}"></div>
@endforeach
```

-->

```
function getdata(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/students/'+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
        $('.students-data').hide();
        $('#students-data-'+id).toggle().html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure you have in your css file

```
.students-data {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IDs should be unique in the DOM. You should do this:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="{{$student->id}}" name="student_lists[]" onclick="getdata( {{ $student->id }} )"/>
        {{$lists->name}}
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="students-data-{{$student->id}}"></div>
@endforeach
```

...

```
function getdata(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/students/'+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#students-data-'+id).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks its showing related data but only div should be visible of selected radio button others should be hide... please do this for me thanks